# Unable to import Custom ModuleMap in swift file Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bridging-header, module-map

I create an encryption c file, header file, `.modulemap` file and also swift file.
I don't really understand how this works. But, the expectation is i can call c function inside swift file.

Some post said to make it happen you need to use Bridging header or module map.

I unable to use bridging header since i'm using framework

```
-Project
 -Project
    -Module
      -encryption.c
      -encryption.h
      -Enc.modulemap
      -Encryption.swift
```

encryption.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* retrieveEncryptionKeyFromC(void) {
    char* key = malloc(7); // Allocate memory for a 16-character key + null terminator
    strcpy(key, "key"); // Example key (replace with your key retrieval logic)
    return key;
}
```

encryption.h

```
#ifndef encryption_h
#define encryption_h

#include <stdio.h>

char* retrieveEncryptionKeyFromC(void);
#endif /* encryption_h */
```

Enc.modulemap

```
framework module Enc  {
    
    umbrella header "encryption.h"
    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

Encryption Swift

```
import Enc //No such module Enc
```

Try to add encryption.c, .h and also module map to compile target build phase. But still not working

How can .modulemap getting call correctly in swift file ?